# Assign different text to labels in multiple UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with custom cells. Everything is working correctly, but what I do not know how to do is assign different text to the labels in each cell. I have one section and three items in each section. I want all three items to have the exact same layout. My thoughts are I need to assign a different identifier for each cell, but I am unsure how I set different text for more than just one cell identifier.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
let reuseIdentifier = "directionCell"

   override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 3
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = "Current title"
    cell.subtitleLabel.text = "Choose to start"
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10




    return cell
```

Comment: show us your source code.

Comment: I edited with the source. It is just the normal boilerplate code of what i had mentioned as i am unsure how to handle assigning text to more than one cell

Comment: Just set the text using something that can take an index (like an array) using the `indexPath` as the way to select the correct text. This is basic stuff - I recommend you follow a tutorial on iTunesU if you are new to Cocoa Touch and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the numberOfItemsInSection to 3, cellForItemAtIndexPath will also be called 3 times.  So, if you have an array of data or information that you want to be displayed then use it in cellForItemAtIndexPath function to get the result that you want.  So, assuming you have an array of titles, use that array in 
the cellForItemAtIndexPath.

```
var titles: [String] = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"]


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
   cell.titleLabel.text = self.titles[indexPath.row]
   cell.subtitleLabel.text = "Choose to start"
   cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10

   return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Christian. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think with collection views, you use the index path's **item** and section (**not** _row_ and section).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 cells and 3 cells has different content, just create 3 collectionviewcels and connect IB outlets and then called theme like this :-

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell!
    let reuseIdentifier = "CustomCollectionViewCell"
    let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell1.titleLabel.text = "Current title"
        cell1.subtitleLabel.text = "Choose to start"
        cell1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell = cell1
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell2.titleLabel.text = "Current title"
        cell2.subtitleLabel.text = "Choose to start"
        cell2.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell = cell2
    } else {
        cell3.titleLabel.text = "Current title"
        cell3.subtitleLabel.text = "Choose to start"
        cell3.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell = cell3
    }

    return cell
}
```